# search a textfile with a textbox

Tags: c#, search, textbox, listbox, text-files

I have a textbox that I want to use to autosearch my text file and display the results in the listbox. the listbox already contains the first item of each line in the text file, so I basically want to search using only the first item of every line in the text file.
The code I currently have does nothing.

```
private void custsearchbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] autosource = File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Suppliers.txt");
        for (int g = 0; g < autosource.Length; g++)
        {
            custsearchbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(autosource[g]);
        }

            custsearchbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    }
```

I want to type the first item in my text box and search my listbox, as I enter my text I want the list to filter out the items that does not match. Please help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
private void supsearchtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listsup.Items.Clear();
        Supfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\Suppliers.txt";
        List<string> proName = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(Supfile))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(supsearchtxt.Text))
                {
                    string[] val = line.Split(',');
                    listsup.Items.Add(val[0]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and it works great.